# How to disable case-sensitivity for filename auto-completion in Emacs 24 shell-mode?

Tags: shell, autocomplete, upgrade, case-sensitive, emacs24

On upgrading from Emacs 23 to Emacs 24, filename completion suddenly became case sensitive in `shell-mode`. I had customized Emacs 23 to be case insensitive in this case but I forget the exact customizations now. Going over my `.emacs` file, I see that `read-file-name-completion-ignore-case` is set to non-nil. However, that seems to have no effect in Emacs 24's `shell-mode`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it turns out that [`shell-mode` in Emacs 24 uses `pcomplete` by default](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2012/01/16/pcomplete-context-sensitive-completion-emacs/). `pcomplete` was always the default for `eshell` but Emacs 24 has made it so for `shell` too.

`pcomplete-ignore-case` controls case sensitivity for `pcomplete`. I got back case insensitivity for filename autocompletion in `shell-mode` in Emacs 24 by adding the following to my `.emacs` file.

```
(setq pcomplete-ignore-case t)
```

Comment: "This variable is obsolete since 28.1; use ‘completion-ignore-case’ instead."